# Unable to get central Device Name via Web-Bluetooth API

Tags: javascript, web-bluetooth

I am trying to fetch the central device name where central is Javascript based web-app and pheripheral is Nano ble 33.

I am using web-bluetooth API and I am able to get pheripheral device name following this [enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BluetoothDevice/name)

and on the other hand, I am able to get the central address using central.address() but I am getting nothing when I am using central.deviceName() or central.localName().

I am wondering where should I setDeviceName() in central. Is it required ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What browser are you using as the Bluetooth API isn't widely supported.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Bluetooth_API#browser_compatibility

Comment: `central.address()`, `central.deviceName()` and `central.localName()` are not part of the Web Bluetooth API specification. It provides no mechanism to get or set the device name for the Bluetooth central. Why does your application need to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to arduino example at https://docs.arduino.cc/retired/archived-libraries/CurieBLE#example-1, it seems like you should be able to get the `BLECentral` with the code below:

```cc
void loop() {
  // listen for BLE peripherals to connect:
  BLECentral central = blePeripheral.central();

  // if a central is connected to peripheral:
  if (central) {
    Serial.print("Connected to central: ");
    Serial.println(central.address());
  }
}
```

However, BLECentral does not allow you get the central device name information according to https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-arc32/blob/master/libraries/CurieBLE/src/BLECentral.h

```cpp
class BLECentral {
  public:
    bool connected(void); // is the central connected
    
    const char* address(void) const; // address of the Central in string form

    bool disconnect(void); // Disconnect the central if it is connected
    void poll(void); // Poll the central for events
...
```

I'd suggest you use the address and use `"Central 00:11:22:33:44:55"` for the name if that's required for you.

To be clear, [Web Bluetooth](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/) does not allow you to get the Central device name. It allows web pages running in the Central role, to connect to GATT Servers over either a Bluetooth connection.

Having said that, nothing prevents you though to have a custom Bluetooth Characteristic on your BLE peripheral that returns the device address of the Central as a value so that you can access it from the web page. See JS example below:

```js
const yourServiceUuid = 0x1234;
const yourCharacteristicUuid = 0x5678;

const device = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
    // filters: [...] <- Prefer filters to save energy & show relevant devices.
    acceptAllDevices: true,
    optionalServices: [yourServiceUuid]});
const server = await device.gatt.connect();
const service = await server.getPrimaryService(yourServiceUuid);
const characteristic = await service.getCharacteristic(yourCharacteristicUuid);

const value = await characteristic.readValue();
const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
console.log(`> Central name: "Central ${decoder.decode(value)}"`);
```

Comment: Thank you for elaborated response. Regarding custom characterstics, I would prefer fetching it from BLECentral. I have already implemented that part. It's just I was looking if somehow I can fetch central device name as you clarified it's not allowed. I am very much fine to specify a custom central device name and vice Versa. Thanks for JS example.

Comment: May I ask why you need the central device name by the way? What's the use case for this?

Comment: I am using a display with my Nano BLE 33. It's just to display the connected device details on screen.

Comment: Just to know more, do we have Auto Connect API?

Comment: You can reconnect to a disconnected BLE device manually. See https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/automatic-reconnect-async-await.html

Comment: Thank you. I checked this. This works well when same session has been maintained. I am trying to autoconnect on page refresh. I tried saving the bluetoothDevice details. but, as the object has huge details. I am unable to store it in localStorage of browser.

Comment: This is a known limitation that will be addressed in the future. You can follow work in progress at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=577953

In the meantime, you can enable the experimental chrome://flags/#enable-web-bluetooth-new-permissions-backend flag to use navigator.bluetooth.getDevices(). It  returns a list of Bluetooth devices a website has access to instead of saving the BluetoothDevice object. See https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/get-devices-async-await.html